# How to make an article's table of contents clickable so it can redirect to a section?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdf, subfloats, article

I'm using Mixtex 2.9 in Windows XP and I'm trying to make my article's table of contents clickable. I tried to add the package hyperref like this:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
```

but it throws the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
\sf@counterlist \relax \def \sf@temp {\@nil }\ifx \sf@temp \@nnil \else \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \sf@setref was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.15
```

What is going on? If I try this in a new article it does work, so how comes it doesn't work on mine?

My article is defined as:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
```

I'm importing these packages;

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                    
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}                               
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}          
\usepackage{wallpaper}                         
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                          
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{marvosym}                           
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{chapterfolder}
```

Comment: There seems to be an incompatibility between the `subfig` package and `hyperref`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In any case you shouldn't load both `subfig` and `subcaption` as they're incompatible.

Comment: Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 6):

The [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package is incompatible with `subfig` (or with the obsolete `subfigure`); anyways, you only need either `subfig` or `subcaption` (not both, and preferably the latter since you are using `caption`), so simply use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                    
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}                               
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}          
\usepackage{wallpaper}                         
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                          
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{marvosym}                           
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{chapterfolder}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks,
   citecolor=black,
   filecolor=black,
   linkcolor=black,
   urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test} 

\end{document}
```

and build you sub-floats with the syntax provided by `subcation`. You could also use `subfig` instead of `subcaption`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                    
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}                   
\usepackage{graphicx}                               
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}          
\usepackage{wallpaper}                         
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                          
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,vmargin=3.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{marvosym}                           
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{chapterfolder}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
   colorlinks,
   citecolor=black,
   filecolor=black,
   linkcolor=black,
   urlcolor=black
}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test} 

\end{document}
```

(and this time use the syntax provided by `subfig`).