# Undefined Control Sequence occurs at: \begin{document}

Tags: errors, document-classes

I wasn't having any problem with my `.tex` file, but after compiling a separate document - which used a different document class - my current file no longer loads.

Specifically, I was using the `imsart` document class, compiled a separate file in the `biom` class, and now my `imsart` file won't load. The error I'm getting is:

```
(c:/Program Files/PCTeX/PCTeXv6/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmss.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \bibsep 

 l.66 \begin{document}
```

I've tried moving the `\begin{document}` around but that doesn't do anything. I'm almost 100% sure it has something to do with the `natbib` package, but I can't figure out what. What's bothersome is that no edits were made to the file, and it was just *after* compiling the other class file that my file won't work.

I've checked to make sure I'm compiling a LaTeX `pdf` file, as I was before.

The basic code is here, which gives the same error, is virtually copied from the `imsart` class website:

```
\documentclass[aoas,preprint]{imsart}
\RequirePackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\startlocaldefs
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\endlocaldefs
\begin{document}
\section{Ordinary text}
  It is interesting that simulations with the \cite{r4} model worked well
 \begin{thebibliography}{9}
 \bibitem{r4}
\textsc{Prokhorov, Yu.} (1956).
Convergence of random processes and limit theorems in probability
theory. \textit{Theory  Probab.  Appl.}
\textbf{1} 157--214.
\MR{84896}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document compiles fine for me. Try deleting your `.aux` file and compile again. BTW: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The title of your question is misleading as the error message that you show is not that `\begin{document}` is undefined. The undefined command is `\bibsep` (which is not a command I recognose)

Comment: I tried deleting the .aux file and compiling. No luck!

Comment: i've changed the title.  the error occurs *at* `\begin{document}` but that is not the error.  the undefined control sequence is `\bibsep`.

Comment: Can you point a source for your version of `imsart.cls`? The one I have bears a release date 2010/04/27. And no error appears with your input, even if I effectively use `natbib` with a mock .bib file. Of course, if you type in directly the `thebibliography` environment, you don't need to load `natbib`, which could solve your problem.

Answer (score 11):

I just had this same problem, and found the solution.

For me, it turned out to be a clash between two packages:
Apparently I was loading both the *subfigure* & *subfig* packages, which are not compatible ([according to this hint](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87122/how-to-make-an-articles-table-of-contents-clickable-so-it-can-redirect-to-a-sec)).

If I comment out either

```
\usepackage{subfigure}
```

OR

```
\usepackage{subfig}
```

The code executes properly.
(*subfigure* is apparently obsolete and should be replaced by *subfig*)

Apparently You should only use one or the other, as they theoretically provide similar functionality, while I was previously loading both one after the other.

Perhaps your class *imsart.cls* is importing both packages?

Answer (score 6):

this may or may not be helpful.  i don't have `imsart` to check.

the undefined command is `\bibsep`.  it is a length defined in `natbib.sty`, and depends
on the length `\@listi` (the width of the space allotted for a first-level item label) being defined already.

for the basic `article` class, `\@listi` is defined in the files `size1*.clo`,
and depends on the command `\normalsize` being invoked; other class files may set
it differently, including delaying the setting until `\AtBeginDocument`.  if the
setting of `\@listi` is deferred, that would explain why the error occurs at
`\begin{document}`.  this appears affect only the `[numbers]` option.

you can check in `imsart.cls` whether `\normalsize` is invoked immediately, or
the setting of `\@listi` is delayed.  if you determine that this
is the case, i think your next action should be to inform the creator/distributor of
`imsart.cls` that the `[numbers]` option of `natbib` is incompatible.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the `imsart` class loaded, but If I change the class to article as,

```
\documentclass{article}
```

Then comment out these two lines, which I'm not sure you need?

```
% \startlocaldefs
% \endlocaldefs
```

And then comment out this one line, with an unfamiliar command,

```
% \MR{84896}
```

Your document compiles fine. You might check and make sure that the `imsart` class file is in your tex tree or in the same folder, but other than that, do you need these lines?

Comment: Thanks Chris:  The imsart .cls file is in the same directory as my .tex folder.  The file compiles perfectly when I remove the "
\RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}"...but of course I've built up a large natbib directory which I'm hoping to use!